# Insert Image into Database without Form Submit AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, slim

I'm trying to insert an image from an type='file' HTML tag into an MySQL database using AJAX.

I'm new to using AJAX for image uploads and i think im getting the syntax wrong somewhere.

I've done some research on this and i think I'm close.

HTML:

```
 <input type="file" id="HTMLmyimage">
```

AJAX:

```
 var $file_data = $('#HTMLmyimage').prop('files')[0];   
    var $form_data = new FormData();                  
    $form_data.append('file', $file_data);



$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false, // important
        contentType: false, // important
        url: "PHPURL",
        data: { 
            'BEimage': $form_data,
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('User Added')
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
$image = $request->getParam('BEimage');

$imageData = (file_get_contents($_FILES[$image]['tmp_name']));

$sql4 = "INSERT INTO customerlocation (CustomerID, Username, img) VALUES ('$CustomerID', '$Username', :img)";
     $stmt4 = $db->prepare($sql4);  
     $stmt4->bindParam(':img', $imageData);
     $stmt4->execute();
```

My current error is saying that $image is not defined but im not sure if im even doing anything before that correct.

Any help on this would be brilliant :)

Thank you

Comment: Interesting that you use parameter binding for JUST the IMG variable but leave the SQL Injection flaw in the query for the other 2 parameters

Comment: Are you using a framework? If not not sure how you got the $request object. Try with $_FILES['BEimage']['tmp_name'] to get the file location.

Comment: @stefansixx1 yes I’m using something called Slim Framwork :)

Comment: Did you check the contents of `$_FILES` ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yea i logged it into the console and the file/image seems to be there but just isnt being passed to the backend via ajax.. Any other suggestions? something so simple is doing my head in

Comment: If you use slim, then you should use `$request->getUploadedFiles()`